# Adobe custom keystroke script to repeat last keystroke

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I am converting a word form to be a fillable pdf form,

I have one section where because the form may be printed and filled in by hand has a input box which is split over two pages.

I found a method [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29147) to link the two fields in adobe so that when the first is full it automatically moves to the next field. However when this occurs the keypress which triggers the script is lost.

Is there anything I can add to the script to repeat the last keypress once the field focus has shifted?

The current script from the answer above is:

```
if ( event.fieldFull || event.willCommit ) this.getField("*name of next field to continue in*").setFocus();
```

Comment: It may be possible, but you would have to add an additional Keystroke event script which would save the last whatever number of characters entered; this may end up to be a little bit messy…